# How can I get the processor "SocketDesignation" with Get-CimInstance?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic, system-information, cim

Since `wmic` calls are deprecated by Microsoft, how can I use `Get-CimInstance` to get the same information as `wmic cpu get SocketDesignation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Win32_Processor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) has a `SocketDesignation` property.  This command produces the same result for me:

```powershell
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' -Property 'SocketDesignation').SocketDesignation
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`Get-ComputerInfo` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo) to get instances of the [`Processor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.processor), which also have a [`SocketDesignation` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.processor.socketdesignation):

```powershell
(Get-ComputerInfo -Property 'CsProcessors').CsProcessors.SocketDesignation
```

In both commands, the `-Property` parameter is selecting specific properties, instead of all available, to be present in the result.

To get the same data as `wmic memorychip list full` you would query, as above, for instances of the [`CIM_PhysicalMemory` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-physicalmemory) or the [`Win32_PhysicalMemory` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) (the latter inherits from the former).  A good way to find the WMI class that contains particular properties is to take a seemingly-unique property name, say `BankLabel`, and [search for it on `learn.microsoft.com`](https://learn.microsoft.com/search/?terms=BankLabel) to see what classes are returned.

Comment: what are the technical aspects or domain related to the above implementation? Is it related to windows drivers?

Comment: wmic memorychip list full --- what will be its equivalent here using get-CimInstance?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the classes used by the `wmic memorychip` alias.  For most hardware I would expect it's up to the driver to implement the respective WMI class properly, but for driver-less components such as processor and memory I would imagine Windows is just querying them directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply type the following command.

```
(Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor).SocketDesignation
```